# solr's suggester gives "SolrException: Unknown Search Component: spellcheck at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore"

Tags: solr

I tried using Solr's `Suggester` component but it gives exception `Unknown Search Component: spellcheck`. I am using solr version 3.6. I made changes in `solrconfig.xml` so it looks like this

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggester">
 <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">suggester</str>
      <str name="field">name</str>
      <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
      <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">spellchecker</str>
 </lst> 
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggester">
  <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggester</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
  <str>suggester</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Now i saved it and started solr but it gives a `500` error. There is a long stack trace which goes like this

```
HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError> in solr.xml ------------------------------------------------------------- org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No cores were created, please check the logs for errors at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:172) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:96) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295) at
```

---lot of lines---

and some more

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown Search Component: spellcheck at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearchComponent(SolrCore.java:893) at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.inform(SearchHandler.java:118) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:527) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:594) ... 32 more
```

According to the stack trace Solr is not able to find the `spellcheck` component but according to the Solr wiki this component comes with Solr version > 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have named your search component `suggester`, and your requestHandler refers to it correctly, so that's probably not where the issue is. Can you check in the rest of your solrconfig.xml whether **some other requestHandler** refers to a component named `spellcheck` in its last-components section or elsewhere? That would throw an error since it can no longer find a component with that name (it's been renamed to `suggester`).

The thing with solrconfig is that it comes with a lot of preconfigured search handlers, and if you change the default name of one item it could cause issues with handlers that refer to it.

Comment: Thanks. i found a `requestHandler` with name `/browse` which has a last-component `spellcheck`. But should i remove that `spellcheck`. Or is there some other way around it?

Comment: You can change that to `suggester`, or you could comment out the entire requestHandler if you don't use it. I suggest the first :)

Comment: I changed that `requestHandler` name to `suggester` but the same error. I tried one more thing and that was i changed the `browse` requestHandler's `last-components` to `components`. In that way it should not ignore later `requestHandlers` which use `spellcheck`. But even that does not solve the problem.

Comment: I didn't mean to change the requestHandler's name to suggester, I meant to replace the occurrence of `spellcheck` in the last-components section to `suggester`.